# How to import firebase storage in web? I got an error everytime I run it. I already got the dependencies in my pubspec

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I got it my pubscpec and I import it whenever I used it like this:

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

FirebaseStorage fs = FirebaseStorage.instance;
```

This is the error I got. I need to upload image [image]